# Fixed and Centered navigation bar, with html

Tags: html, css

The code below should make the navigation panel centered and fixed. However, it does not meet the "centered" criteria, only fixed.

Any ideas what I have done wrong ?

```
<tr style="position:fixed">
  <td class="bgnavigator" "align="center" height="40" valign="top">
    <table align="center" ><tr><td>{NAVIGATOR}</td></tr></table>
  </td>
</tr>`
```

Comment: What is not being centered? Are there any CSS files being enacted on this page?

Comment: This index.htm file is from a template downloaded from a website editor. i will edit the comment to show full file, sorry if i left something out.

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea how to add the code here so that its not auto translated....

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong is *using a table row for a toolbar*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you you want to center table just add this CSS to the root table element:

```
margin-left: auto
margin-right: auto
```

Furthermore you shouldn't use deprecated inline css-attributes like align, valign. It's deprecated. Use CSS only styles.

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/mVzsY/

Comment: And remove " before align="center"